# copying installed binaries from linux machine

Tags: linux, binary, centos

I recently installed a program from binaries. Unfortunately, I had not copied the source to a personal repo . the host of the binaries has decided not to support it anymore, and is not hosting it

However, we have chosen to stick to this version. I do have access to machines with this software installed.

Is it possible to copy the binaries from the installed software?

This was installed using `rpm -i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically yes.
you need to find all files installed with a package and copy all of them to corresponding path in target machine but it depends on package and scripts has been run before/after file copy in package installation process.

for finding files installed from an rpm you can try this:

```
# rpm -ql httpd
```

RPM options used:

- -q : this is a general rpm query
- -l : list package content